# What prevents people from using viewbots on Youtube to earn money?

Tags: youtube

View bots seem like relatively simple to make programs that I think could allow someone to get like 30 cents for each 30 second ad which is $36 per hour of easy money. Does Youtube have a defense against this like a Captcha or something? With machine learning Captchas I believe can be solved even.

Comment: And perhaps with machine learning such bots can be recognized?

Comment: Huh I never thought of that but I think it's probably easier to disguise than be recognized. Easier to encrypt than to decrypt. I think the bot could change IPs each time it views the video

Answer (score -1):

I am fairly sure YouTube uses some form of machine learning for this, but I can think of a few methods they might use here to aid in combating bots:

- Tracking the IP address
- Tracking mouse movement and activities to ensure you are a real human (like the CAPTCHA's that "automatically" sign you in)
- Tracking behavior from cookies from other services and checking whether you are following an existing pattern or not
- Other hidden methods

Google doesn't openly publish things like these (as a simple Google search would show), but we can make educated guesses as to how they *could* do it.